# Unable to finish the Memories sub-event?

Tags: rune-factory-4

I have already triggered the post-content quest Memories. According to various guides, I have completed all steps but the last in which I visit Ventuswill's room where a cutscene with the Guardians should play. However, the cutscene just won't trigger whatsoever! Is this a bug, or is there another factor that should be considered that's required to finish this event?

For clarification, these are the steps I've found in various guides. This text comes from [[this walkthrough]](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/635388-rune-factory-4/faqs/69308), and shows to have the same described steps [[in this guide]](http://therunefactory.wikia.com/wiki/Random_Events_(RF4)) on the Rune Factory wiki:

> 1: Day 1: Visit flower shop when Amber and Dylas are there for
>   scene
>  2: Day 2: Visit clinic for scene with Dolce and Pico
>   3. Day 3: Visit the Inn for a scene with Barrett and Leon
>   4. Day 4: Visit Venti's spot for a scene
>   5. Day 5: Visit the Inn for scene with Raven and Dolce
>   6. Day 6: Visit Venti's spot for scene with Guardians, tell them you want to    help and are ready, see scene with Arthur and Kiel, go to
>   Leon Karnak,    defeat statues and Sarcophagus, enter Rune Prana!

Comment: You may want to add the steps you've taken to the question, or at least link to the guides you've been using, so we'll know what all you've already done.

Comment: I'm in the same situation as you. I tried skiping days in game, different times of the day, but no sucess. I wish they had left an option of cancelling a town even,it seems like a softlock. Did you manage to find workaround? If so, how? Since i've found only your thread, it seems that this bug is very especific. :(

Answer (score 1):

You probably missed talking to Raven after the scene with her and Dolce. You should get a surprisingly long conversation with her about the nature of family. 
(I didn't immediately realize that the conversation was part of the event, until I started wondering why Raven was so uncharacteristically talkative.) If it's not Raven then it'll be someone else you need to talk to, so talk to everyone.